# Desplegar arreglo en HTML

Tags: array, lista

debo de crear un arreglo al cual le ingreso datos a través de mi pagina, ya que ingreso todos los datos debo desplegar estos en forma de lista incluyendo la posición de estos en el arreglo. lo logro con 2 funciones pero a la hora de desplegar la lista, para poder regresar a mi pagina principal y agregar otro dato, tengo que refrescar y me borra todos los datos de mi arreglo.
como puedo hacer para que esto no pase. que al dar click en el boton desplegar muestra la lista allí mismo sin necesidad de refrescar o cambiar la pagina.
Agrego el código que tengo.

```
   <html>
   <head></head>    
   <body>
   <!--<form>-->
   <p>
   <b><h1>Arreglos #4</h1></b>
   <br/>
   </p>
        Programa Estacionamiento.: 
   <br/>
   <br/>
   </br>
   <br/>
         Ingresa los siguientes colores de automoviles:
   <br/>
         Rojo, Gris, Azul, Amarillo, Verde.
   <br/>
   <br/>
          <input id="color" type="text"/>
    <br/><br/> 
          <input type="button" value="Guardar" onclick="guarda()"/><br/>
    <br/>
          <input type="button" value="terminar" onclick="terminar()"/><br/>
          <script type="text/javascript"></script>

          <script>

             var arreglo = [];
             var pos = 0;
             var resultado = '';
 
             function guarda( ){
                var colores = document.getElementById("color").value;
                //alert("entro");
                arreglo.push(colores);
                //alert(arreglo);}
             }  
             function terminar(){
             arreglo.forEach(function (elemento,indice,arreglo) {
              resultado = ("("+ pos +")"+ ".-"  +  elemento);
             // alert (resultado + ("\n"));     
             document.write(resultado);
             document.write("<br>")    
             pos = pos +1;
              });
             }     
     </script>
    <!--</form>-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Se borra porque nunca lo persistes en ningún lado. Mételo al [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que [Document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/write) se usa bastante poco en la práctica, ya que tiene algunos inconvenientes como el que tu te has encontrado.

Cuando se renderiza el documento HTML, lo hace desde arriba hacia abajo y en ese momento está en estado `open`, cuando utilizas `Document.write()` en ese momento escribe en pantalla lo ingresado como argumento en el lugar donde se encuentra la función (respetando el contenido anterior)

Ejemplo:

```html
<h1>Primera línea</h1>
<script>
 document.write("<h2>Segunda línea</h2>");
</script>
<h3>Tercera línea</h3>
```

Al terminar de renderizar (llega al final del archivo) pasa a estar en estado `close` y ahora `Document.write()` funciona distinto, lo que hace es sobrescribir todo el contenido anterior, lo cual a ti te da la impresión de que hubo un refresco de página (lo cual no es así), aunque técnicamente si hubo un refresco de contenido.

Ejemplo:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  document.write("<h2>Segunda línea</h2>"); //Solo se verá esto
});
```

```html
<h1>Primera línea</h1>
<h3>Tercera línea</h3>
```

---

Lo anterior es para explicar porque tu código tiene ese comportamiento, pero como te decía al principio esta función rara vez se utiliza.

Lo que se usa habitualmente para agregar contenido a una página se hace seleccionando una etiqueta HTML y se agrega contenido a ella. La mayoría de las etiquetas aceptan contenido (los `input` no lo hacen) y también existen varias formas de agregarlo.

Yo te daré un ejemplo de cómo creo que es la forma más fácil

- Se crea un `div` para mostrar el array, cuya id será `salida`
- Usaremos la propiedad `innerHTML` para agregar contenido a ese div como string en formato `HTML`

```js
const arreglo = [];
const salida =  document.getElementById("salida");


function guarda() {
  const colores = document.getElementById("color").value;
  arreglo.push(colores);

}

function terminar() {
  salida.innerHTML =""; //limpiamos
  arreglo.forEach(function(elemento, indice, arreglo) {
    salida.innerHTML += `(${indice}).-${elemento}<br>`;
  });
}
```

```html
Ingresa los siguientes colores de automoviles:
<br/> Rojo, Gris, Azul, Amarillo, Verde.
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="color" type="text" />
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="Guardar" onclick="guarda()" /><br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="terminar" onclick="terminar()" /><br/>
<div id="salida"></div>
```